# Operator "|" usage is c raspberry pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, i2c

I am using raspberry pi to read a gyroscopic data. Am new to it but so far I understand everything that I am basing my code from besides the use of "|" in it.
When looking it up it says its "bitwise OR" operator but in my situation it doesnt make sense, than again I don't understand the explanation on Wikipedia.

The line that uses it looks as follows

```
readBlock(0x80 | OUT_X_L_G, sizeof(block), block);
```

readBlock is user defined function as follows.

```
readBlock(uint8_t command, uint8_t size, uint8_t *data) {
int result = i2c_smbus_read_i2c_block_data(file, command, size, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `0x80 | OUT_X_L_G` is returning a value of `OUT_X_L_G` with a bit number `7` set:

```
OUT_X_L_G = xxxx xxxx
  bitwise or
0x80      = 1000 0000
---------------------
result    = 1xxx xxxx
```

The logic behind the whole function call should be determined by the context you are not providing.

Comment: So what it's doing is setting the bits 1xxxxxxx then when reading it it allows for x's to be filled with what it reads from those bits? I didn't think the rest would be necessary but I'll update the post with the function.

Comment: `x`s - are the original bits taken from `OUT_X_L_G`. It is modifying the 7th bit only, in case it was `0` or leaving it `1` as is if it was `1`.

Comment: About the update: Is it working? It doesn't look correct, if you ask me (well, I still don't have the whole picture)..

Comment: So if it was for example 0x10 00010000 then it would only modify the 4th bit which is 1? what about 00100010 would it be modifying the 1ns?

Comment: It is not working. it is giving me a constant value. I am trying to understand everything I am doing "copying" to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: When ORing with ? Yes.

Comment: `OUT_X_L_G` is the command, perhaps b5 set (by my brief search). It is not "filled in", but the expression ensures that b7 of the command is also set, for some reason.

Comment: @WeatherVane So that's weird, as  `OUT_X_L_G` seem to be an address of a register, not a command..

Comment: yes OUT_X_L_G is a adress in hex equivlent to 0x28.

Comment: The readBlock from my understanding is. Also I tried to look for documentation of i2c-dev.h but couldnt find any. I'm assuming it has a specific name i don't know.

Comment: Well, you can look [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol). But it doesn't indicate why the high bit should be `1` though..

Comment: OK, [found it](http://ozzmaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/LSM9DS0.pdf). It says: `" the 7 LSb represents the actual register address while the MSB enables the
address auto increment"`. So here you give the start address and giving the command to automatically increment the address to read the whole block.