# Reading from raspberry pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi2

I am attempting to read gyroscopic data using a raspberry pi and am having a lot of problems. I think I understand a lot of the code and it is written properly.

The problem comes in when printing it onto raspberry screen, all I get is constant numbers that don't change at all.

Everything is based off of http://ozzmaker.com/berryimu/ I know the code is provided but I wanted to learn and possibly optimize it for my purposes. I am using https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/L3GD20H.pdf gyroscope.

The program to read values is:

```
    #include </home/pi/gyroSetup.c>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        setup();
        int i;
        int G[3];
        for(i = 0;i<=1000;i++){
            readGyro(G);
            printf("%d ", G[0]);
            printf("%d ", G[1]);
            printf("%d\n", G[2]);
        }
    }
```

The gyroSetup.c is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "fcntl.h"
#include "linux/i2c-dev.h"

#define Gyr_adress 0x6b
#define Gyr_ctrl1 0b1110100 
#define Gyr_ctrl4 0b00000000
#define Gyr_odr 0b00000000

int file;

void readBlock(uint8_t command, uint8_t size, uint8_t *data) {
    int result = i2c_smbus_read_i2c_block_data(file, command, size, data);
    if(result != size) {
        printf("Failed to read block from i2c!");
    {
}

void readGyro(int *T) {
     uint8_t block[6];
     if(ioctl(file,I2C_SLAVE, Gyr_adress) < 0) {
         printf("failed to select device!");
     }
     readBlock(0x80 | 0x28, sizeof(block), block);
     *T = (int16_t)(block[0] | block[1] << 8);
     *(T+1) = (int16_t)(block[2] | block[3] << 8);
     *(T+2) = (int16_t)(block[4] | block[4] << 8);
 }

void writeGyro(uint8_t location, uint8_t value, int file) {
    if(ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, Gyr_adress) < 0) {
         printf("Failed to select i2c device");
    }
    int result = i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(file, location, value);
    if(result == -1) {
        printf("Failed to write byte!");
    }
}

void setup(){ 
    __u16 block[I2C_SMBUS_BLOCK_MAX];
    file = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR);
    if( file < 0) {
         printf("Unable to open i2c bus!");
    }
    writeGyro(0x20, Gyr_ctrl1, file);
    writeGyro(0x23, Gyr_ctrl4, file);
    writeGyro(0x39, Gyr_odr, file);
}
```

I have no idea why when reading the values don't change so please help. When compiling there are no errors.

Comment: Following OP's [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861462/operator-usage-is-c-raspberry-pi)

Comment: This code has mismatched braces, are you sure it compiles

Comment: First: Check if the WHO_AM_I_G-register has the correct content (should be 0x48) to verify that basic communication is established and working. Then, you seem to have only enabled the Z-Axis, you should set ctrl4 to 0x77. And you only read 1000 values, isn't that read too quick? Maybe just use an endless loop for testing.

Comment: It is all very well copying someone's sample code and expecting it to work, but now you are "having a lot of problems", and this is another. If it had worked, how much would you have understood? Without following the sample, I suggest you take it small step by step. Write your initialisation code, based on sample, check everything you can, and so on. Then set another small step forward.

Comment: `#include </home/pi/gyroSetup.c>` Not good!

Comment: when writing it I was writing step by step and checking. It does compile but I had to take it from raspberry pi by retyping it so some small errors are probably there. It was set to use only one axis at the moment to make sure I understand it.

why is my include not good?